# Batch file can't delete a file "that's in use" but the file doesn't seem to exist?

Tags: windows-7, batch, temporary-internet-files

I have this simple batch script:

```
cd "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files"
del *.* /f /q
pause
```

When I run it, it tells me that it cannot delete `\Temporary Internet Files\counters.dat` because it's in use and quits. I am able to manually delete all of the contents of the folder myself though, without changing anything in regards to what applications are running. Also, I do have Hidden Files/Folders set to show up and I don't even *see* a counters.dat file... Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Maybe its hidden? I found this relating to that file: http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2015-020312-2256-99&tabid=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Batch file can't delete a file “that's in use” but the file doesn't seem to exist?

`counters.dat` is visible for me:

```
C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files>dir /a
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C8D0-DF1E

 Directory of C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files

10/06/2015  21:29    <DIR>          .
10/06/2015  21:29    <DIR>          ..
08/01/2015  23:31    <DIR>          AntiPhishing
11/01/2015  08:28    <DIR>          Content.IE5
04/01/2015  16:50               128 counters.dat
10/06/2015  21:29                84 desktop.ini
10/02/2015  12:03    <DIR>          gegl-0.2
05/02/2015  23:44    <DIR>          inkscape
08/01/2015  23:31    <DIR>          Low
29/05/2015  12:16    <DIR>          SQM
03/01/2015  17:11    <DIR>          Virtualized
               2 File(s)            212 bytes
               9 Dir(s)  83,685,535,744 bytes free
```

It cannot be deleted:

```
C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files>del counters.dat
C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\counters.dat
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files>
```

Using `resmon` we can see which processes are using the file:

[image]

You won't be able to delete `counters.dat` **while any processes have it open**.

---

**"Why does a dir show 1 file and N directories, but when I browse to this location in Windows Explorer I see 0 directories and 83 files?"**

Windows 7 and 8 create Virtual Folders to store files that Internet Explorer tries to save in protected locations.

The data is actually written in a virtualized hidden folder, that mirrors the actual path and is stored under the `Temporary Internet Files` folder.

It seems that `explorer` and `dir` treat virtual folders differently in how they are displayed.

`Cygwin ls` can at least display the contents of Content.IE5 which `dir` cannot.

```
DavidPostill@Hal /c/Users/DavidPostill/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Temporary Internet Files
$ ls -al Content.IE5
total 692
drwxrwx---+ 1 DavidPostill   None 0 Jan 11 07:28 .
drwxrwx---+ 1 DavidPostill   None 0 Jun 10 21:29 ..
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None 0 Jun 11 13:07 4EIQY12G
drwxrwx---+ 1 DavidPostill   None 0 Jan  8 22:31 969NZU3P
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None 0 Jan 10 23:18 97RLMZJM
drwxrwx---+ 1 DavidPostill   None 0 Jan  8 22:31 ARML5AYH
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None 0 Jan  4 15:50 container.dat
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None 0 Jun 11 13:23 DO6HI19N
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None 0 Jan  9 23:28 FQECM0IG
drwxrwx---+ 1 DavidPostill   None 0 Jan  8 22:31 HY66GH4K
drwxrwx---+ 1 DavidPostill   None 0 Jan  8 22:31 IM8A2PXZ
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None 0 Jun 11 13:07 KHCCNELO
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None 0 Jan  9 23:28 MAX18LP0
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None 0 Jun 11 13:08 OJ3O062M
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators None 0 Jan  9 23:28 YTDLISE8
```

---

> Windows 7 | 8 also creates Virtual Folders to store files that Internet Explorer tries to save in protected locations. So, instead of causing an ‘add-on’ to fail when it tries to write a data file to the Windows folder or Program Files, Windows 7 or Vista redirects the write operation to a virtual equivalent. Thus, the program continues to operate, believing that it wrote the files to the system location; little realizing that the data actually got written in a virtualized hidden folder, that mirrors the actual path and is stored under the ‘Temporary Internet Files’ folder.

Source [Temporary Internet Files Folder Location](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/temporary-internet-files-folder-location)

Comment: Interesting catch there. Why does a `dir` show 1 file and N directories, but when I browse to this location in Windows Explorer I see 0 directories and 83 files?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see you edited your post. I'm tied up working on something else right now, but thank you so much! I will be sure to come back an Accept it when I can take a look.